# Поиск по регулярному выражению SQL все кроме цифр?

Tags: sql, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM `dle_post` WHERE `xfields` REGEXP 'number|123([^[:digit:]]|$)'
```

Делаю так, но все равно выводиться записи те у которых 12345 и так далее, как сделать чтобы он выводил только 123 у кого запись ?

Дальше может идти знак | или пустота.

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: я хочу получить запись со значением number|123 а не number|12345 и так далее

Comment: [отредактируйте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1278463/edit) и добавьте в него пример данных и желаемый результат, а еще лучше создайте соответствующий [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) - это максимально увеличит ваши шансы получить __рабочее и проверенное__ решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знак `|` должен экранироваться `\`, так как является специальным символом, обозначающим альтернативы.

Если я правильно понял задачу, то выражение должно быть следующим.

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM `dle_post` 
WHERE `xfields` REGEXP '^number\|123\|?$'
```

Добавил еще `^` для обозначения начала строки. `?` - 0 или 1 совпадение.